# GeocodeModel in Qt

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, openstreetmap, geocode

I'm writing a  the little app with using the QT/QML, and i have problem with GeocodeModel in my app. I don't know, why it doesn't work. I did it with YT tutorial, but by the man it works.

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2
import QtQuick.Window 2.0
import QtLocation 5.6
import QtPositioning 5.6

ApplicationWindow {
    id: app_window
    visible: true
    width: 1024
    height: 800
    title: qsTr("Navigation")
    PositionSource {
        active: true
        onPositionChanged: {
            map_id.center = position.coordinate;
        }
    }
    Rectangle {
        id: mapRectangleID
        width: 1024
        height: 800
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
        anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
        Map {
            id: map_id
            anchors.fill: parent
            plugin: Plugin { name: "osm" }
            center: QtPositioning.coordinate(51.320729390711975,12.280097007751465)
            zoomLevel: 15
            MapQuickItem {
                //coordinate: QtPositioning.coordinate(59.91, 10.75)
                sourceItem: Image {
                    id: endPointImage
                    source: "assets/marker.png"
                    width: 40.1
                    height: 34.3
                } //size and position of maker
                anchorPoint.x: endPointImage.width / 2
                anchorPoint.y: endPointImage.height
            } //marker
            RouteModel {
                id: routeBetweenPoints
                plugin: Plugin { name: "osm" }
                query: RouteQuery {id: routeQuery }
                Component.onCompleted: {
                    routeQuery.addWaypoint(QtPositioning.coordinate(51.318784,12.2773504 ));
                    routeQuery.addWaypoint(QtPositioning.coordinate(51.3117764,12.280909000000065 ));
                    //routeQuery.addWaypoint(endPointGeaocodeModel)
                    update();
                }
            } //start and end point
            MapItemView {
                model: routeBetweenPoints
                delegate: Component {
                    MapRoute {
                        route: routeData
                        line.color: "red"
                        line.width: 10
                    }
                }
            }//linie, die beide punkte verbindet
            GeocodeModel{
                id: endPointGeaocodeModel
                plugin: Plugin { name: "osm" }
                query: "Sandakerveien 116, Oslo"
                onLocationsChanged: {
                    if (count)
                        endPointImage.coordinate = get(0).coordinate;
                }
                Component.onCompleted: update()
            } //suche den platz mit strasse und stadt
            Rectangle{
                id:_ifStartPointLongitude
                width: 100
                height: 20
                border.color: 'gray'
                border.width: 2
                x: 900
                y: 120
                anchors.left: app_window.right
                TextInput {
                    id: txtPlainStartPointLongitude
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    anchors.margins: 4
                }
            }
        } //all widgets and items of map
    } //size and position of map
}
```

and This element doesn't work:

```
GeocodeModel{
    id: endPointGeaocodeModel
    plugin: Plugin { name: "osm" }
    query: "Sandakerveien 116, Oslo"
    onLocationsChanged: {
        if (count)
            endPointImage.coordinate = get(0).coordinate;
    }
    Component.onCompleted: update()
} //suche den platz mit strasse und stadt
```

I tried too another cities,streets, but it still doesn't work. Can someone explain me, what i did/wrote wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is caused because the item Image does not have the coordinate property, the one who has the coordinate property is the MapQuickItem, so we must set it to that item so we must give an id to the MapQuickItem, to observe the image we will establish the center of the map to the same coordinate.

```
// ...

MapQuickItem {
    id: marker_id // <---
    sourceItem: Image {
        id: endPointImage
        source: "assets/marker.png"
        width: 100
        height: 100
    } //size and position of maker
    anchorPoint.x: endPointImage.width / 2
    anchorPoint.y: endPointImage.height
} //marker

// ...

GeocodeModel{
    id: endPointGeaocodeModel
    plugin: Plugin { name: "osm" }
    query: "Sandakerveien 116, Oslo"
    onLocationsChanged: {
        if (count> 0){
            marker_id.coordinate = get(0).coordinate // <----
            map_id.center = get(0).coordinate // <----
        }
    }
    Component.onCompleted: update()
} //suche den platz mit strasse und stadt

// ...
```

Comment: Ok, i thought all the time, that i shuld write the id of the image and not of the MapQuickItem

Comment: @DragonCoder how strange, I tested it and it works correctly, in the following image I show you the result: https://imgur.com/a/FBFMTt0

Comment: @DragonCoder could you show me a picture of what you get

Comment: @DragonCoder whats is your `zoomLevel`?

Comment: @DragonCoder I see a red circle, is not that the icon?

Comment: The oom lvl isn't important, beacous i scroled it, and the image is chang his size of scroling.

Comment: serialnmea: No serial ports found
Failed to create Geoclue client interface. Geoclue error: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Disconnected
QGeoTileProviderOsm: Tileserver disabled at  QUrl("http://maps-redirect.qt.io/osm/5.8/satellite")
QGeoTileFetcherOsm: all providers resolved

Comment: No the red circel is of the osm

Comment: @DragonCoder I think the error is caused by your provider: `Geoclue error: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Disconnected QGeoTileProviderOsm`, what version of Qt do you have ?, I had the same problem in Qt 5.10, updates to Qt 5.11. also install geoclue

Comment: i have qt 5.10. im now in school. i will do it after school, and will give u answer.

Comment: yeah it's working now. Do u know, how i can do or use a loop in qml?

Comment: @DragonCoder a for loop in QML is similar to the other languages: `for (var i = 0; i <some_limit; i ++) {some_operation(i)}`, as I pointed out you should ask a question for POST, so if you still have problems with the for then I invite you to publish a new question offering a [mcve]